# How to create consistent x axis values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a graph in ggplot. I want the x axis to have commonly used values that make it easy to read. For example, `-50%, -25%, 0%, 25%, 50%`

I have a data frame `data` that looks like:

```
Specialty,PercentageChange,mycolor
T,-20.23%,brown
T,-20.29%,brown
```

```
 graph<-ggplot(data, aes(x=PercentageChange, y=Specialty,color=mycolor,size=5)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_gray(base_size = 14)
```

This creates the graph, however, the x values are all the exact values from the graph:

[image: text]

I have tried `+ coord_cartesian(xlim =c(-100, 100))`
However, it makes the graph looks less than ideal:
[graph](https://gyazo.com/c39ec3ff6e34f87405be4ef490b3dc14.png)

I have tried `scale_x_continuous(labels = c(-100,-50,0,50,100,150,200))`
but I receive:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: Please provide the output from `dput(data)` to make your question reproducible. or `dput(head(data, 20))` if it is a huge data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `PercentageColumn` is a character (a discrete variabe) so that each value is treated as a unique category.

Hence, convert first to a numeric using e.g. `readr::parse_number`. As a second step you could label as percentages and set your desired breaks and limits via `scale_x_continuous`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- structure(list(Specialty = c(TRUE, TRUE), PercentageChange = c(
  "-20.23%",
  "-20.29%"
), mycolor = c("brown", "brown")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -2L
))

data$PercentageChange <- readr::parse_number(data$PercentageChange) / 100
ggplot(data, aes(x = PercentageChange, y = Specialty, color = mycolor, size = 5)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), breaks = seq(-1, 1, .25), limits = c(-1, 1)) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 14)
```

[image]